# If $T(X)=AX$ then $T$ and $A$ have the same eingenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $K$ be a field and $A\in M_2(K)$. Let
\begin{align}
T:\ M_2(K)&\longrightarrow M_2(K)
\\ X&\longmapsto T(X)=AX
\end{align}
be a $K-$linear map on the vector space $M_2(K)$. I want to check if $A$ and $T$ have the same eingenvalues.

My attempt : if $\lambda\in K$ be eingenvalue of $A$ then
$$\exists v\ne0:\ Av=\lambda v. $$
Let $v=\begin{bmatrix}a\\ b\end{bmatrix}$. Since $v\ne 0$, we can assume without loss of generality that $a\ne0$. Consider $u=\begin{bmatrix}a^{-1}& b\end{bmatrix}$. We have
$$vu=\begin{bmatrix}1& ab\\ ba^{-1}& b^2\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$\lambda(vu)=Avu=T(vu) $$
hence $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

But I got some struggle for the inverse direction. Could someone give me a help ? Thank you.

Comment: In fact it might help you to observe that any value for $u$ would work. The idea is that the value $AX$ is the same as what you get if you apply $A$ to each column of $X$. So suppose $X$ is an eigenvector of $T$. What must $A$ do to the columns?

Comment: I don’t think I catch your mean

Comment: @PermQi The suggestion was that if $X = [X_1 X_2]$ where, say, the column $X_1\ne 0$ and $AX=\lambda X$, then this must mean $AX_1=\lambda X_1$. What does that tell you?

Comment: how about the case $X_1 = 0$ and $X_2\ne0$ ?

Comment: How about it? Do you see how similar reasoning works for that case?

Comment: I got it, thanks alot